# Java static variable in cluster environment

Tags: java, static, cluster-computing

[Designing J2EE Applications for Real-Life Clustered Environments](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/07/14/clustering.html)

this article said cannot use java static variable in cluster environment, but if we want to use the static variable like feature (only one copy of value shared by all object in a clustered application) what should we use?

Comment: Note that this article was written in 2004, while some content is still true, I would not use this as a reference.

Comment: you might want to consider immutable inner class as "only one copy of value shared by all object"
If the shared state are some basic data type, final instance variable should fit in your requirement.

Comment: If your data are not changed during the operations (e.g. you loaded some property file) you can use `static`. The only drawback is that you have to initialize twice (once for each JVM). If the data are changing, you have to use some replication method to keep track of the changes, or have a "single source of truth" like databases, memcache, etc.

Comment: @GaborSch what replication method to keep track of the change? Need self-implemented (self coding the method)?

Comment: I don't recommend home-grown solutions. Like I put in my answer: `@ApplicationScoped` could be a solution. Also forget `@Singleton`, because actually it is a *Stateless* bean, you must not keep data there.

Answer (score 5):

A static variable can only be accesed by one Java Virtual Machine, loaded with one class loader. If you need to share this value to several JVM, you can use a database, a cache (memcached, redis), or any other external system.

Comment: we always declare constants using Public Static Final modifier, in cluster environment, we should not use this to declare constant because only one JVM can access this constant?

Comment: You won't have problems with constants (you will have a "copy" of the constant in every node), but when you have a "static" variable (not final), it can be modified, and will have the same value for every read from every classes (this is not always true when working with threads, that can "copy" the value locally), but only from one JVM. If you have a distributed application (remote EJB, for example), you will modify the value "locally" in that JVM (will not be modified in every JVM (maybe even in different host machines).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make it `@Stateful` bean with `@javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped`.

I haven't tried this, but it seems to me that GlassFish 3.1 should support it (at least the documentation does not deny it).